# Folder manipulation in python

Tags: python, directory

I have many folders named as 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, folder1, folder2 inside my xpto folder.
I want to get only the folders named with numbers (they are always between 0 and 2) and move to another folder.
So, I want to know what folders I need to move and I'm trying to print them. The code doesn't answer anything!

```
import os
import shutil
import numpy as np

pasta="xpto"

lista=[]
lst=np.arange(0.05,1,0.05).round(2)
for i in lst:
    lista.append(i)

for foldername in os.listdir(os.path.join(xpto)):
    if foldername in lista:
        print(foldername)
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "move to another folder" ? An naive idea but efficient to test if a folder's name is a number is to try to convert it to a float inside a `try` block. If the folder's name is not convertible to a float, it will produce an error and run the `except` block.

Comment: Or you could also check that the folder's name is made of digits and eventually a dot. `if all(c in '0123456789.' for c in folder_name) and folder_name.count('.')<=1:`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're using numpy for basic math and directory code, but basically you just want to iterate over your listdir and check the name anyway you want:

```
for folder in os.listdir(...):
   if folder[0] in ('0', '.', '1', '2'):
       # something
   # or use other logic like parse the foldername:
   try:
       number = float(folder)
   except ValueError:
       # not a number
   else:
       # it is a number
```